# Interactive CAD/FEM simulation result as 3D-PDF with media9

Tags: 3d, media9

I want to include a FEM simulation result in my thesis as an 3D interactive object. I am looking for a way to show the actual stress value when you click on an area on the 3D-Object.

With `media9` I have successfully implemented a SolidWorks 3D-Object with FEM result texture into a LateX PDF using following method:

Export FEM sim result as .wrl and import it into Meshlab. Then export it from Meshlab as .U3D with color option ticked.

But how do I implement the actual simulation result data, so that I could click on the object and it displays the stress value? Maybe if somehow the texture is linked to a stress value array. I have figured out a way to export the stress values including x,y,z coordinates in a csv table. So I have that.
I don't yet have enough experience with the scripting options of media9 yet, so I don't know what's possible with it.

Alternatively I would try to import the color chart as a floating 2D image.

My LateX code right now. (Different views are externally defined in `myview.vws`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[3D]{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.9\linewidth, height=0.6\linewidth, activate=pageopen, 3Dtoolbar=true, 3Dviews=myviews.vws, 3Dmenu,    
  ]{\includegraphics[]{fem_fallback.PNG}}{fem_model.u3d}
    \caption{3D-PDF}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction or has solved this problem already, your help is highly appreciated!
Thank you for your answers!